# java.io.IOException using iText

Tags: java, io, itext

I will not waste my and your time in exposing my conjectures, my deductions, my hypothesis...
so, "ex abrupto" (premise: I am using a stream in order to produce a pdf with iText):
This is the code:
in the action

```
public String getPDF() {
    PdfPratDTO dto = (PdfPratDTO) sexxion.get("pdfprdto");
    String numprat = dto.getNumPrat();
    String intest = dto.getIntest();
    ArrayList<PratDettAvanzDTO> avzs = dto.getDetavz();

    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    Document document = new Document();
    try {
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, buffer);

        document.open();

          StaticElements.addMetaData(document, numprat, "P");

          try {
              BodyElements.addTitle(writer, document, numprat, intest, "P");
          }
          catch (MalformedURLException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

          BodyElements.addContents(document, avzs, "P");

          document.close();
      }
      catch (DocumentException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

      setInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.toByteArray()));

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

No problems calling

```
StaticElements.addMetaData(document, numprat, "P");
```

and not even calling

```
BodyElements.addTitle(writer, document, numprat, intest, "P");
```

the document is printed correctly showing these elements, but when I add

```
BodyElements.addContents(document, avzs, "P");
```

i.e.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void addContents(Document document, Object data, String type) throws DocumentException {

    Paragraph header = new Paragraph();
    StaticElements.addEmptyLine(header, 3);

    if (type.equals("U"))
        createTable(header, (UserDTO) data);
    else if (type.equals("P"))
        createTablePrat(header, (ArrayList<PratDettAvanzDTO>) data);
    document.add(header);
}

private static void createTablePrat(Paragraph header, List<PratDettAvanzDTO> avzs) throws BadElementException {
    float[] columnWidths = {8,33,5,10,9,9,5,7,14};
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(columnWidths);

    PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Date"));
    c1.setFixedHeight(21f);
    c1.setBackgroundColor(new BaseColor(221, 232, 250));
    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    table.addCell(c1);

    c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Description"));
    table.addCell(c1);

    c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("St. Pr. Code"));
    table.addCell(c1);

    etc.etc.

    c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Purpose"));
    table.addCell(c1);
    table.setHeaderRows(1);


    System.out.println("-> createTablePrat.size()=" + avzs.size());
    //TODO

    header.add(table);
}
```

the document is still printed but still like before i.e. without this new element and, in the best cases (best... just to look) the console output remains hanged, in the most cases shows the following error

```
07/06 12:35:10| ERROR [http-apr-10080-exec-9] (CommonsLogger.java:38) - Exception occurred during processing request: java.io.IOException: APR error: -730053
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: APR error: -730053
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:353)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:317)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:110)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StreamResult.doExecute(StreamResult.java:301)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:186)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:367)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:271)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:238)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:238)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
        at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:544)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2463)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2452)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: APR error: -730053
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.writeToSocket(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:291)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.writeToSocket(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:244)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalAprOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(InternalAprOutputBuffer.java:213)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.flush(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:305)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:765)
        at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:179)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:349)
        ... 70 more
```

I really have not the faintest idea, even because if, in `addContent(...)` method, I call the `CreateTable()` method, which is identical to the first one except for the number of columns, the header labels, and the fact that retrieves data just by a single dto instead from a list of dtos, everything works wonderfully!

Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Solved (somewhat by chance) by completing the `createTablePrat(...)` method (I subsitued "//TODO" with the true loop over the List and (miracolously) works).
Who explains why?
Maybe the "guilty" is `table.setHeaderRows(1);` that creates a kind of suspension?